# Increment input name array index using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am beginner to UI designing and jquery.
I am trying to increment the input name array index using jquery. I have an add button and clicking on it will add another row. But the name of the row should have name with incremented input array index value.

Here I require the `paramKey[]` and `paramValue[]` index value to increment as we click on an *Add* button.

Script I have written:

```js
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addCF").click(function() {
    i++;
    $("#paramsFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th></th><td><input  style="margin-left: 187px"  type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldName" name="paramKey[i]" value=""/> &nbsp; <input type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldValue" name="paramValue[i]" value=""/> &nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
  });
  $("#paramsFields").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="paramsFields">
  <tr valign="top">
    <td scope="row"><label for="paramFieldName">Params</label></td>
    <td><input style="margin-left: 187px" type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldName" name="paramKey[0]" placeholder="Param Name" /> &nbsp;
      <input type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldValue" name="paramValue[0]" value="" placeholder="Param Value" /> &nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try to put `var i=1;` inside `.ready()`

Comment: @Roy i have tried. I am getting this error: 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "i"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have first index inputs in html code like `name="paramKey[0]"`.
In javascript code you start index with 1 `var i = 1` but before you append new inputs you increasing the index `i++`, that should be after appent inputs, and the index variable "i" value should be print in input name attribute `name="paramKey[' + i + ']"`. And the id must be unique, so I add the index value on id name also.

I change your code and have look the change to understand.

```js
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addCF").click(function() {
    $("#paramsFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th></th><td><input  style="margin-left: 187px"  type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldName' + i + '" name="paramKey[' + i + ']" value=""/> &nbsp; <input type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldValue' + i + '" name="paramValue[' + i + ']" value=""/> &nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
    i++;
  });
  $("#paramsFields").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="paramsFields">
  <tr valign="top">
    <td scope="row"><label for="paramFieldName">Params</label></td>
    <td><input style="margin-left: 187px" type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldName" name="paramKey[0]" placeholder="Param Name" /> &nbsp;
      <input type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldValue" name="paramValue[0]" value="" placeholder="Param Value" /> &nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I'll do to keep it easy:

- Keep HTML in HTML, by creating a template of your new data (hidden using CSS),
- Use a placeholder, a special character to be replaced by your number,
- Clone, replace the placeholder, and append this template when clicking the button.

Working snippet (see comments for details):

```js
var i = 0; // Start at 0
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addCF").click(function() {
    i++;
    var newRow = $("#template").clone().removeAttr("hidden").removeAttr("aria-hidden"); // Clone template and make it visible
    $(newRow).html(newRow.html().replace(/%/g, i)); // Replace the % by the i number
    $("#paramsFields").append(newRow);
  });
  $("#paramsFields").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="paramsFields">
  <tr valign="top">
    <td scope="row"><label for="paramFieldName">Params</label></td>
    <td><input style="margin-left: 187px" type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldName" name="paramKey[0]" placeholder="Param Name" /> &nbsp;
      <input type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldValue" name="paramValue[0]" value="" placeholder="Param Value" /> &nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="template" valign="top" hidden="true" aria-hidden="true">
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input style="margin-left: 187px" type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldName" name="paramKey[%]" value="" /> &nbsp;
      <input type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldValue" name="paramValue[%]" value="" /> &nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Note: All your styling should be done in CSS.

Comment: Hi @Takit lsy, really you are great.

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda Thanks :) I'm glad it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you are appending always hard codeded value and hence output is coming same whereas you i is increasing properly

```
 $("#paramsFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th></th><td><input  style="margin-left: 187px"  type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldName" name="paramKey['+i+']" value=""/> &nbsp; <input type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldValue" name="paramValue['+i+']" value=""/> &nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
```

});

Here I have added the i as variable in your code replace this line in your code

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not getting incremented array index value for `paramKey[]` and `paramValue[]` is because you are not appending variable `i` properly.

Try the following code:

```
 <script>
   var i = 1;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".addCF").click(function() {
        i++;
        $("#paramsFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th></th><td><input  style="margin-left: 187px"  type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldName" name="paramKey['+i+']" value=""/> &nbsp; <input type="text" class="code" id="paramFieldValue" name="paramValue['+i+']" value=""/> &nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
      });
      $("#paramsFields").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
      });
    });
</script>
```